# How to connect a directive with a controller in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am refactoring some angularjs with a new directive and I am trying to access a controllers scope from the directive.
Here is the directive:

```
(function () {

    /**
    * Config
    */
    var moduleName = 'eBayPartsFinder.directives.categoryFilters';

    /**
     * Module
     */
    angular.module(moduleName, []).directive('categoryFilters', categoryFiltersDirective);

    function categoryFiltersDirective() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                model: '=',
                disabled: '=',
                onChange: '&'
            },
            templateUrl: BASE_URL + '/lib/EbayPartsFinder/CategoryFilters.html',
            link: categoryFiltersLinkFn
        };

        function categoryFiltersLinkFn($scope, element, attrs, ctrl, transclude) {
            
            $scope.Init = function () {
                var category = sessionStorage.getItem(`EbayPartsFinder.BatchResults.Category.${$scope.Batch.Id}`);
                var subCategory = sessionStorage.getItem(`EbayPartsFinder.BatchResults.SubCategory.${$scope.Batch.Id}`);
                if (category) {
                    $scope.FiltersStaging.BatchFilters.CategoryId = category;
                }
                if (subCategory) {
                     $scope.FiltersStaging.BatchFilters.SubCategoryId = subCategory;
                }
            }

            $scope.Init();

        }
    }
})();
```

In my controller I have

```
searchResultsController = function ($scope, $http, $timeout, shoppingCart) {

$scope.Init = function () {
        $scope.Filters = {
            BatchFilters: {
                ManufacturerId: null,
                BrandId: null,
                CategoryId: null,
                SubCategoryId: null
            },
            GlobalFilters: {}
        };
        $scope.FiltersStaging = angular.copy($scope.Filters);
        $scope.CategoryOptions = [{ Id: null, Description: "" }].concat($scope.Categories);
        $scope.SubCategoryOptions = []; 
    }
}
```

I need access to $scope.Categories or $scope.CategoryOptions in the directive. Is there a way I can access/modify it in the directive?

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices to use a Controller in a directive.

1. Do not use a local scope within the directive. Then you have access to your existing controller.

`
return {
restrict: 'E',

```
        scope: false,

        templateUrl: BASE_URL + '/lib/EbayPartsFinderCategoryFilters.html',

        link: categoryFiltersLinkFn
    };`
```

2. Or use your own controller

`
return {
restrict: 'E',

```
        scope: {

            model: '=',

            disabled: '=',

            onChange: '&'

        },

        templateUrl: BASE_URL + '/lib/EbayPartsFinder/CategoryFilters.html',

        controller: contollerFn,              

        link: categoryFiltersLinkFn

    };`
```

The function contollerFn() is to be defined in the same way as the function categoryFiltersLinkFn().